# How to convert epoch time to Date in CAPL

Tags: epoch, capl

I am not able to find predefined function in CAPL scripting language for converting epoch time to Data starting at 01.January.1985 00:00:00.

Can anyone suggest me  how to convert epoch time to Date in CAPL

Answer (score 0):

The timestamps in CANoe start at the begin of the simulation, not at the begin of the epoch.

Therefore no such function exists in CAPL. You would have to write one yourself.